# What are these called in ASP.NET <%: %>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are these called in ASP.NET?

- `<%# ... %>`
- `<%= ... %>`
- `<%: ... %>`

And what are the different variations?
How are each of them used?

Comment: I agree that it's hard to find that kind of words in SO or even Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a code block.  The version with the `#` is used for data binding.  They basically allow you to embed C# code into your aspx page.

MSDN has a good article on code blocks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and a good article on data binding expressions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The generic term for the tags like `<% %>` is "nuggets", with the exception of `<%@ %>` which is called a directive.

How each nugget is used can be found at [.NET "code nugget blocks"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205546/net-code-nugget-blocks).