# What does the <#= symbol mean?

Tags: asp.net, server-tags

What `<#` this symbol means in the asp.net
It is inside the html  tag.

```
 <td><#= userInfo.observerResponseKey != null ? (userInfo.observerStatus == '<%= Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), Status.Draft) %>' ? "Draft shared " +  userInfo.observerDateSubmittedString : userInfo.observerStatus == '<%= Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), Status.Private) %>' ? "In Progress" :  "Completed " + userInfo.observerDateSubmittedString) + " by " + userInfo.observerName : "Not Started"  #></td>
```

I want to add img to the td if the result is "In progress" or "completed".

I tried adding like

```
 <td><#= userInfo.observerResponseKey != null ? (userInfo.observerStatus == '<%= Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), Status.Draft) %>' ? "Draft shared " +  userInfo.observerDateSubmittedString : userInfo.observerStatus == '<%= Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), Status.Private) %>' ? "In Progress" :  "Completed " + userInfo.observerDateSubmittedString) + " by " + userInfo.observerName #><img src="../../images/icon_delete_red.png" /> <#= : "Not Started"  #></td>
```

But its throwing error "Unparse Microtemplate"

So, what is that tag <#= mean? and how can I add an image in this code?

Please help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957284/whats-the-deal

Answer (score 1):

Embedded code blocks.

```
<%# %> is for data-binding expressions
```

For example, in an ASP.NET `GridView`, many times you will see something like this:

```
<%# Eval("DataColumnName") %>
```

There are several other varieties of these:

```
<%= %> is the equivalent of `Response.Write()`
<% %> runs server-side code, like an if-else block
<%: %> is for HTML-encoding the data
<%@ %> is for directives, usually page directives in ASP.NET
```

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - yes, thanks for catching that. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a code block or a "code nugget". Essentially it allows you to embed code to be processed and rendered by the server before being sent to the client.

See this [.NET "code nugget blocks"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205546/net-code-nugget-blocks)

or

[What are these called in ASP.NET <%: %>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532837/what-are-these-called-in-asp-net?lq=1)

An example :

```
<img id="<%= someValue.ToString() %>" src"http://website.com/someImg.jpg" />
```

Comment: Yes when this is rendered by the server it comes to the client as pure html, so you can do whatever you need with html elements. This is merely a mechanism to inject server side variables into your html.

Comment: But how to add the img tag? Should i close the server tag before using img tag and after the img tag to open the server tag again? If I did so, its throwing error

Comment: @Kokila If this answered your questions, please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/templatesclientside

Telerik uses this syntax for code templates