# ASP User control: Cannot pass parameter from within a loop

Tags: asp.net, .net, ascx, aspx-user-control

I can't pass a variable to an user control (ascx) from an asp page (aspx) within a loop.

I want to recursively iterate a custom control with a foreach loop (would like to avoid **asp:Repeater**, but if it's the only solution I'm open to suggestions about that.

I Used all the server [inline tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154310/diference-between-special-tags-asp-net) I know, but result either gets the full

```
<%= stringvalue %>
```

to the control (meaning in the string variable which receives the parameter in the control, I see the expression and not the value) or null when I use binding tags

```
<%# stringvalue %>
```

Here's what I'm doing in the aspx file:

```
<%foreach (string item in listItems)
                    {
                        tempItem = item;
                        %>
                    <uc:CustomControl runat="server" id="controlId" AutoPostback="true" parameterCustom='<%# Eval("tempItem")%>'/>

                <%
                    }%>
```

And in the control I have

```
public string parameterCustom {get;set;}
```

which should receive the value

Comment: @freefaller Sorry, fixed. My code is as it's shown now <%# Eval("x") %>

Comment: I've never tried to create multiple controls this way, I've always used a `<asp:Repeater>` which I'm aware you'd like to avoid. My main concern here is having multiple controls with an `id` of `controlId`

Comment: @freefaller I'll try that way waiting for answers

Comment: Use a Repeater...

Comment: @VDWWD I tried to avoid Repeater because it's clunky and retarded