# How to return HTML in an ASP.NET ListView ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, listview, webforms

- I am using VS2013 .NET 4.51 writing a WebForms application
- The object contains some HTML via Item.QuestionText property

The problem is that I actually get the actual HTML eg. `<strong>Some Text</strong>` instead of **Strong Text**. Trying with HtmlEncode() has no effect.

So can anyone tell me how I can get the HTML to render correctly within the template?

```
<asp:ListView runat="server"
   ID="providerDetails"
   ItemType="Arithmetika.ExternalUserControls.DataTypes.QuestionVewModel"
   SelectMethod="GetQuestions">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
       <td><%#: Item.QuestionNumber %></td>
       <td><%#: HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Item.QuestionText) %></td>
     </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

---

**Edit:** And for more on code nuggets see: [.NET "code nugget blocks"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205546/net-code-nugget-blocks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `Item.QuestionText` returns `<strong>Some Text</strong>` you don't need to HtmlEncode it.

`<%#: %>` tag would apply HtmlEncode (the : operator). Have a Read of this [Scott Gu post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Try this; it should work (note that there is no colon)

```
<%# Item.QuestionText %>
```