# enable and disable asp validator using embedded code in asp tag dosent work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

enable and disable asp validator using embedded code in asp tag doesn't work, The value is written but control still is enabled. Please check the occurrences of

```
Enabled="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(txtText.Enabled) ? false : true%>"
```

in this form:

```
<form id="frmValidator" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ValidationSummary
            ID="Summary"
            runat="server"
            HeaderText="Error(s):"
            CssClass="msg-error" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" MaxLength="15" Enabled="false" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            ID="rfvtxtText"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtText"
            ErrorMessage="Requiered."
            Display="None"
            ClientValidationFunction=""
            SetFocusOnError="true"
            Enabled="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(txtText.Enabled) ? false : true%>" />

        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
            ID="revtxtText"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtText"
            Display="None"
            ErrorMessage="Invalid."
            ValidationExpression="[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ,.*]{3,50}"
            SetFocusOnError="true"
            Enabled="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(txtText.Enabled) ? false : true%>" />

        <asp:Button
            ID="btnSave"
            runat="server"
            Text="Save" />
    </div>
<form>
```

Comment: `txtText.Enabled` does not need converting to boolean, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but still is not working  Enabled="<%# txtText.Enabled ? false : true%>"  the validator continue with a true value

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you cannot.

`<%# %>` is [Data Binding Expression Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You cannot use it without ServerControl such as GridView, ListView.

Normally, we disable/enable control from code behind.

### Javascript Method

Another approach is to disable validation using Javascript. However, you need to redirect to different page or do something after a button click. Otherwise, validation message will be displayed back to user after post back.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById('<%= txtText.ClientID %>').getAttribute('disabled') === 'disabled') {
        alert('disabled');
        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rfvtxtText.ClientID %>'), false);
        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= revtxtText.ClientID %>'), false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: disable validation using javascript change enebled value to false but still validator continue firing massage, i alert the validator and it is false

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be possible. Though I'm still a rookie myself, I always forget which code-nugget does what. I'd try `<%: --expression-- %>`.
The second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205546/net-code-nugget-blocks) question does a pretty good summary.

Comment: Try with just <% --code-- %>. You should be able to use almost anything anywhere. Just remember to use a semicolon ( ; ) after the code in that nugget, just like in code-behind.